# Posting-a-photo usecase in android and server

Tags: android, server, photo

I want to have the posting-a-photo usecase in my android app.

This is the scenario I have implemented:

**1.** User posts a photo.

**2.** On the client side I scale the photo* , compress it and send 
it to the server.

**3.** I store the photo on the server.

**4.** Users, who can view the photo, fetch the photo from the server.

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't take into consideration
the different-screen-sizes problem.

Let's say user **A** posts a photo.

User **B**, which has a phone with a larger screen**, fetches the photo
from the server. The photo doesn't fit good in the environment
since it has fixed width and height determined by user **A** (scaling in step 2).

I cannot simply scale the photo and put it into user B's ImageView, because
I am risking to loose the aspect ratio of the photo.

One approach that comes to mind is to simply remove the step **2** from the scenario. 
I send the photo to the server, and when a user tries to fetch it 
I scale the image according to the user's screen size (which I receive as parameters in the fetch request).

The problem with this approach is that, on each request, I will have
to scale the photo on-the-fly and send it to the client. 
Another problem is the efficiency of uploading a photo, because I don't scale the photo (before uploading it). 
It takes much more time to upload a full 2MB (or even a 500KB) photo than to simply upload a scaled photo (~20KB).

What are my options?
Since I am relatively new to Android, chances are that I am missing something essential.

Cheers!

---

*I scale maintaining the aspect ratio.

** Sorry for the terminology, i don't know how and when to use high density/pixels correctly. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have own dedicated server with unlimited traffic and 4T HDD. So, basically what I do is:

1. User take a picture by phone
2. User upload image to the webserver
3. Using ImageMagick + mozjpeg 3 I resize image 3 times and save it with prefixes small_, medium_, large_ OR with prefixes pre size: 1024_, 640_...
4. Now, my app can find user's screen dimensions and load image by doing request for specified prefix.

My arguments for doing in this war are:

1. Free traffic
2. Big HDD
3. Fast user's internet speed
4. When upload in another thread, and show to user another activity, he doesn't feel the "long waiting time" for uploading large images.
5. You always can resize photo on device, from 10Mb to 2Mb, for example, and on server do other resizes.

Now about image ratio. There you cannot to do a lot. You must decide, what to do in case that user with large screen and own aspect ratio tries to load image that was uploaded by user with small screen and own aspect ratio.

The truth is that screen size doesn't matter. What is matter is a ratio. So, you can load image, put it in ImageView, and this will filled with black background if the image is "smaller". O r you can load large size of image, crop it and put it to the ImageView. Larger image is used only for better quality.

In my case, I always do crop images if I use it as preview. I think it's looks more beautiful. When user want to view full size image, I download full image and show it as is.

Answer (score 2):

A good server that handles images should:

- receive images at high-quality
- save or cache the images in multiple sizes (small, medium, large)
- serve images according to a size parameter (larger phones ask for the large image)

There are many solutions for this kind of server. Most of them resize the image on-the-fly and cache the result. The client tells the server what size it wants. One example is the image handling in Google Play. Go to the play webside and view the urls of the app-icons ([example](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oa7F2tMRe-RKDmQbz4TXLAvrwYmxgtkIQQ1A0aQHSrn47HcaEYJ6eLufUw-O-7OdeLY=w300-rw)). They have a width parameter.

You can also think of a maximum dimension (like 2048px) and resize the image before upload only if needed.

The client that views the image needs to decide on what size it asks from the server or it can resize the image on the phone, instead of relying on the server. Do this if traffic is not an issue. Consider using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to make things easier.

Regarding aspect ratio: The client that views the image should handle this. It should expect any aspect ratio and be prepared for it. Use android:scaleType on the ImageView and decide which scale type fits your scenario. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) are the scale types. If you don't want black lines and want to occupy as much as possible from the screen, use CENTER_CROP - but you might end up losing parts of the image.

Answer (score 0):

In most apps the original aspect ratio in maintained and two black "stripes" are added if your screen doesn't match.

I think it's not possible to manage all screen ratios...

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` has `android:scaleType` attr that preserves aspect ration to be broken,
like `fitCenter` or `centerInside`
And also calculate size of fetched image and set view size by yourself.